# Why is my code Producing folders without md or makedir?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

So im making a script to turn letters into different frequency for me and a buddy but just as i figure out how to make it work it starts to bug on me and starts creating folders without make dir or md commands.

```
@echo off

:top
set /p in=
SET strterm=
SET mytext=%in%
SET tmp=%mytext%%strterm%
:loop
SET char=%tmp:~0,1%
SET tmp=%tmp:~1%
echo %char%
```

That filters through characters to give me my output with 'If' statements

```
if %char% == a (powershell -Command "[console]::Beep(200,200)") && goto abd
if %char% == b (powershell -Command "[console]::Beep(220,200)") && goto abd
and so on... [a-z A-Z 0-9 <space> ;+=/\,.@`~#{}[]().-_': ]
```

Then

```
:abd
IF NOT "%tmp%" == "%strterm%" GOTO loop
goto top
goto end
:end
powershell -Command "[console]::Beep(10000,300)"
```

Out of that does anything look like it would make a folder?

Here is a video on the issue https://youtu.be/3LLGj2brD2w
Heres the full code https://pastebin.com/e0qPeaU6

Comment: Do not use `tmp` or `temp` as variables. They have a special meaning (location of temporary files).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename the `tmp` variable to fix the program.

`tmp` and `temp` are environment variables that point to the temporary files folder in your computer.

Comment: Could you add an explanation? ([Magoo’s comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47543315/why-is-my-code-producing-folders-without-md-or-makedir#comment82043848_47543315) seems to describe the reason.)